# Telerik Rad grid Insert and Update command not firing their events

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, telerik-grid

I am working on a project where Telerik Controls are used. Earlier, grid was having 2 template columns with command button column for firing edit and delete command. Clicking on edit will automatically convert the edit button to an update button, and delete becomes cancel. Everything was working fine, until now.

Later I added two more textboxes inside that grid as templated column. And made relevant changes in code where the child controls are unboxed. But, on running, I found that the events are not firing.  That is, Insert and Update; cancel, edit and  delete are working fine.

One more thing, on clicking page does a postback, but the event is not fired.

Any ideas based on this scenario?  Might be anybody already faced such conditions.

*Note: I am working on remote Terminal, so clipboard operations and Internet are blocked there. We can only connect, write, compile, and execute code there. So I can't paste here the code for help.*

Comment: Perhaps you could write a small sample that repeats the problem?  There are too many things that could be wrong.  and without seeing your code, it's impossible to narrow it down.

Comment: Possibly you've just introduced a syntax error when adding the new template columns?

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed, it was weird by anyhow I got it working. Issue was in radgrid template column i added an attribute visible ="false" and that made me sick. I removed that and every thing went fine..

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem. I was explicitly binding the grid. I took that out and used NeedDataSource function. That solved my problem.

So if any one faces this issue, verify whether you are binding the grid anywhere else in the code behind file.